# easily get text appended to a node on d3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, this, nodes

I can't get my head around the d variable conventionnally used in d3.

Once the graph is generated, i'd like to pass the text value as a variable on click (or at least log it on console).

```
        const node = svg
          .append("g")
          .attr("stroke", "#fff")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(nodes)
          .join("circle")
          .attr("r", 15)
          .attr("stroke", "none")
          .style("fill", "none")
        const text = svg
          .append("g")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(nodes)
          .join("text")
          .text((d) => d.word)
          .style("cursor", "pointer")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");
          .on("click", (d) => console.log(/*value of text here as string*/))
        node.append("title").text((d) => d.id);
```

I tried console.log(d) and it displays a whole load of infos without an easy path to the value of the clicked text.

Comment: Have you tried `(d) => console.log(d.word)`? That's the property used for the text.

Comment: yes i tried, i get "undefined"
the best attempt was (d.target) which gives me
```
<text stroke="black" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" style="cursor: pointer;" x="506.5" y="443.5">thing i want</text>
```

Comment: Try `(d) => console.log(d.data)` and see what the properties of the object are. If you're using the usual d3 node, everything should be in there.

Comment: Yep that's the complicated way of getting the text value. I thought maybe there was a simpler way.

Comment: It's the direct way. What i mean is that  your word property is like there, as in  `(d) => d.data.word`.

Comment: gets me "undefined", same with data.text

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the fastest way but good enough I guess

```
(d.path[0].firstChild.data)
```